# Convert multiple level list of nested dictionaries into single list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert multiple level list of nested dictionaries into a single list of dictionary

input:

```
list_ = [
 {'Name': 'Paras Jain',
  'Student': [{'Exam': 90,
               'Grade': 'a',
               'class': [{'age': 10, 'subject': 'hindi'},
                         {'age': 11, 'subject': 'maths'}]},
              {'Exam': 99,
               'Grade': 'b',
               'class': [{'age': 14, 'subject': 'evs'},
                         {'age': 15, 'subject': 'science'}]},
              {'Exam': 97,
               'Grade': 'c',
               'class': [{'age': 10, 'subject': 'history'}]}]},
 {'Name': 'Chunky Pandey',
  'Student': [{'Exam': 89,
               'Grade': 'a',
               'class': [{'age': 9, 'subject': 'no'}]},
              {'Exam': 80, 'Grade': 'b', 'class': []}]},
 {'Name': 'abc', 'Student':[]}
]
```

Required output:

```
[{'Exam': 90, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 10, 'subject': 'hindi'},
 {'Exam': 90, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 11, 'subject': 'maths'},
 {'Exam': 90, 'Grade': 'b', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 14, 'subject': 'evs'},
 {'Exam': 90, 'Grade': 'b', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 15, 'subject': 'science'},
 {'Exam': 97, 'Grade': 'c', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 10, 'subject': 'history'},
 {'Exam': 89, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Chunky Pandey', 'age': 9, 'subject': 'no'},
 {'Exam': 89, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Chunky Pandey', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'abc', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @brunson Please check my solution. Looking for more optimized solutions. If you have any ideas please contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```py
for d in list_:
    if not d.get('Student', []):
        if 'Student' in d:
            d['Student'].append({})
        else:
            d['Student'] = [{}]


df = pd.json_normalize(list_, record_path='Student', meta='Name').explode('class', ignore_index=True)
out = df.join(df.pop('class').apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns=0).to_dict(orient='records')
```

```
print(df)

   Exam Grade                              class           Name
0  90.0     a    {'age': 10, 'subject': 'hindi'}     Paras Jain
1  90.0     a    {'age': 11, 'subject': 'maths'}     Paras Jain
2  99.0     b      {'age': 14, 'subject': 'evs'}     Paras Jain
3  99.0     b  {'age': 15, 'subject': 'science'}     Paras Jain
4  97.0     c  {'age': 10, 'subject': 'history'}     Paras Jain
5  89.0     a        {'age': 9, 'subject': 'no'}  Chunky Pandey
6  80.0     b                                NaN  Chunky Pandey
7   NaN   NaN                                NaN            abc

pprint(out, width=150)

[{'Exam': 90.0, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 10.0, 'subject': 'hindi'},
 {'Exam': 90.0, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 11.0, 'subject': 'maths'},
 {'Exam': 99.0, 'Grade': 'b', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 14.0, 'subject': 'evs'},
 {'Exam': 99.0, 'Grade': 'b', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 15.0, 'subject': 'science'},
 {'Exam': 97.0, 'Grade': 'c', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 10.0, 'subject': 'history'},
 {'Exam': 89.0, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Chunky Pandey', 'age': 9.0, 'subject': 'no'},
 {'Exam': 80.0, 'Grade': 'b', 'Name': 'Chunky Pandey', 'age': nan, 'subject': nan},
 {'Exam': nan, 'Grade': nan, 'Name': 'abc', 'age': nan, 'subject': nan}]
```

Comment: The built in [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module can be helpful for formatting dictionary output in a readable way. e.g. `from pprint import pprint; pprint(out, width=150)`

Comment: @BeRT2me Thanks, don't know the `width` parameter.

Comment: No problem, also, there's nothing special about `150` here. It just needs to be a number big enough to fit each dictionary on a single line, but not so big that it fits them all on a single line. For this particular case, it looks like any number ~90 through ~570 work the same.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh As I check your solution is looking good to me but the dictionary repeating. Can you please help me with this? So your total number of dictionaries is 11 but the expected was 8.
and also you didn't handle the condition if 'Student': [] is blank list.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I tried your solutions with 2700000 records it takes too much time to execute. Is it possible to optimize more?

I update my solution. Please check .

Answer (score 0):

Optimized, Tested with 72 million records produced in 41 seconds

For your completely blank `[{}] * 900000` example, it finished in 0.42 seconds:

```
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint
from time import time

def make_record(name: str, 
                exam: str='NA', 
                grade: str='NA', 
                age: str='NA', 
                subject: str='NA') -> dict:
    return {'Name': name, 
            'Exam': exam,
            'Grade': grade, 
            'age': age, 
            'subject': subject}

def fix_record(data: dict) -> list:
    new_data = []
    name = data.get('Name', 'NA')
    students = data.get('Student', [])
    if students:
        for student in students:
            exam = student.get('Exam', 'NA')
            grade = student.get('Grade', 'NA')
            classes = student.get('class', [])
            if classes:
                for c in classes:
                    age = c.get('age', 'NA')
                    subject = c.get('subject', 'NA')
                    new_data.append(make_record(name, exam, grade, age, subject))
            else:
                new_data.append(make_record(name, exam, grade)) 
    else:
        new_data.append(make_record(name))
    return new_data

list_ = [
 {'Name': 'Paras Jain',
  'Student': [{'Exam': 90,
               'Grade': 'a',
               'class': [{'age': 10, 'subject': 'hindi'},
                         {'age': 11, 'subject': 'maths'}]},
              {'Exam': 99,
               'Grade': 'b',
               'class': [{'age': 14, 'subject': 'evs'},
                         {'age': 15, 'subject': 'science'}]},
              {'Exam': 97,
               'Grade': 'c',
               'class': [{'age': 10, 'subject': 'history'}]}]},
 {'Name': 'Chunky Pandey',
  'Student': [{'Exam': 89,
               'Grade': 'a',
               'class': [{'age': 9, 'subject': 'no'}]},
              {'Exam': 80, 'Grade': 'b', 'class': []}]},
 {'Name': 'abc', 'Student':[]}
]
list_ *= 9e6

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time()

    list_ = list(chain.from_iterable(map(fix_record, list_)))

    print(f'{time()-start:.2f} seconds')
    print('Total Records: ', len(list_))
    print('First 10 Records:')
    pprint(list_[:10], width=150)

    list2 =  [{}] * 9e6
    start = time()
    list2 = list(chain.from_iterable(map(fix_record, list2)))
    print(f'{time()-start:.2f} seconds')
    pprint(list2[:10], width=150)
```

Output:

```
41.02 seconds
Total Records:  72000000
First 10 Records:
[{'Exam': 90, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 10, 'subject': 'hindi'},
 {'Exam': 90, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 11, 'subject': 'maths'},
 {'Exam': 99, 'Grade': 'b', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 14, 'subject': 'evs'},
 {'Exam': 99, 'Grade': 'b', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 15, 'subject': 'science'},
 {'Exam': 97, 'Grade': 'c', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 10, 'subject': 'history'},
 {'Exam': 89, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Chunky Pandey', 'age': 9, 'subject': 'no'},
 {'Exam': 80, 'Grade': 'b', 'Name': 'Chunky Pandey', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'abc', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 90, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 10, 'subject': 'hindi'},
 {'Exam': 90, 'Grade': 'a', 'Name': 'Paras Jain', 'age': 11, 'subject': 'maths'}]

0.42 seconds
[{'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'},
 {'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', 'Name': 'NA', 'age': 'NA', 'subject': 'NA'}]
```

Comment: The solution looks very optimized but I think you forget one more scenario if 'Student': []
that is if the Student key is blank.

As your output contains 7 records Expected was 8. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Ah, you added in the blank student after I answered....

Comment: Yeah, Because I realized that case also. Have you edited the answer?

Comment: @user_123 Updated my answer. As long as there's never more than one nested list per (nested) list, this should work.

Comment: This solution is not reliable because I tried with 2700000 records it takes too much time to execute. You can also try. I just copied the code and run it in my local.

Comment: Can you check my solution. Is it possible to convert it into list Comphresion. @BeRT2me, liked your optimized code

Comment: `map(func, iterable)` can be re-written `[func(x) for x in iterable]` but I believe it'll be slightly less efficient.

Comment: ok thanks! let me check

Answer (score 0):

I tried below two ways but looking for a more optimized way:
How I tested for **2700000 records**. **Just multiple [{}] * 900000**

**1st way**

```
# tested with 2700000 records
import time
start_time = time.time()
rows = []
for data in list_:
    if data['Student']:
        for row in data['Student']:
            row['Exam'] = row['Exam']
            row['Grade'] = row['Grade']
            row['class'] = row['class']
            row['Name'] = data['Name']
            rows.append(row)
    else:
        rows.append({
            'Exam': '',
            'Grade': '',
            'class': [],
            'Name': data['Name']
        })

res = []

for data in rows:
    if data["class"]:
        for in_row in data['class']:
            in_row['Exam'] = data['Exam']
            in_row['Grade'] = data['Grade']
            in_row['age'] = in_row['age']
            in_row['subject'] = in_row['subject']
            in_row['Name'] = data['Name']
            res.append(in_row)
    else:
        res.append({
            'Exam': data['Exam'],
            'Grade': data['Grade'],
            'age': '',
            'subject': '',
            'Name': data['Name']
        })


end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
# 15.956519842147827
```

**2nd way**

```
# First, fix your empty class list, so pd.json_normalize doesn't ignore it:
import time
import pandas as pd
start_time = time.perf_counter()
for i, x in enumerate(list_1):
    if not x['Student']:
        list_1[i]['Student'] = [{'Exam': 'NA', 'Grade': 'NA', "class": [{}]}]
    else:
        for j, y in enumerate(x['Student']):
            if not y['class']:
                list_1[i]['Student'][j]['class'] = [{}]


# https://towardsdatascience.com/
#all-pandas-json-normalize-you-should-know-for-flattening-json-13eae1dfb7dd
df = pd.json_normalize(list_1, record_path=['Student', 'class'], meta=['Name', ['Student', 'Exam'], ['Student', 'Grade']])
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Student.', '', regex=False)
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('age', 'Student.class.age', regex=False)
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('subject', 'Student.class.subject', regex=False)

dict_ = {
    'age': 'Student.class.age',
    'subject': 'Student.class.subject'
}
# inplace = true because we just modify the working data frame if we pass #inplace = false then it returns a new data frame.
df.rename(columns=dict_, inplace=True)
df = df.fillna('NA')

out = df.to_dict('records')
end_time = time.perf_counter()
print(end_time-start_time)
# 54.662456035614014
```